# Como usar imagenes de fondo en Xamarin form?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hola me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto en Xamarin Form para ios y android y me gustaría saber cuales serian las resoluciones para imágenes de fondo, hasta donde se las imágenes e iconos se ubican en la carpeta "Resources/drawable" para android y "Resource" para ios. Repito mi pregunta, cuales resoluciones les debo dar a unas imágenes que deseo poner de fondo de pantalla.

Comment: Hola, resolviste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Pues en Android existen las carpetas drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi , etc, precisamente para tener varias resoluciones de cada imagen y se ajusten de acuerdo a lo que se necesita; algo parecido ocurre en iOS, por lo tanto te sugiero utilizar esta [página web](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/) para subir las imágenes y que queden con el formato que se requiere en cada una de las dos plataformas y luego las agregues a tu proyecto.

En cuanto a la resolución, hice algunas pruebas con imágenes de 375x812 pixeles y se ven muy bien de fondo. Te recomiendo que cualquier imagen o icono que utilices en un proyecto de Xamarin Forms sea primero tratado(a) con la página web referenciada arriba de forma que te cree las carpetas y las resoluciones correctas.